# Ad Hoc: Sharing a wifi connection in use?

Tags: adhoc

Say my laptop is connected to a WiFi hotspot. Is it possible to simultaneously create an ad-hoc network for that same laptop, so I can connect my phone to my laptop instead of directly to the WiFi hotspot?

The wifi reciever in my laptop is much stronger than in my phone, that's why I'd like to see if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

No  you can't do it in ubuntu.You can not connect to two different network using same interface. You will need a another wireless adapter or repeater.

This is currently only possible in windows 7 with windows 7 certified driver for the wireless.In windows 7 , there are technology to virtualize a physical adapter.

`Intel My wi-fi`, `Connectify` are  the softwares to do this in windows 7 .

If supported virtual adapters will be listed like below picture

[image: wi-fi virtual]